# How to display a specific category and its children by the categories ID number?

Tags: php, magento

I am using Magento and have a category under the ID `99`. I want to display it and its children using an HTML unordered list. How?

Comment: I think you confused question and answer...

Comment: So I reworked the structure and I hope this question is more useful than before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently my category model request wasn't specific enough below is the solution and fixes the problem of getting the correct url.

```
<ul class="menu-list-1">
  <li>
    <h2>
      <a href="<?php echo Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load(99)->getUrl() ?>">
        <?php echo Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load(99)->getName() ?>
      </a>
    </h2>
  </li>
  <?php foreach (Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(99)->getChildrenCategories() as $childCategory): ?>
    <li>
      <a href="<?php echo $childCategory->getUrl(); ?>">
        <?php echo $childCategory->getName(); ?>
      </a>
    </li>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I copied and reformatted this code from the original question. Credits to Clint Hubbard Jr.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <h2>
      <a href="<?php echo Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load(99)->getUrl() ?>">
        <?php echo Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load(99)->getName() ?>
      </a>
    </h2>
  </li>
  <?php $children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories(118) ?>
  <?php foreach ($children as $category): ?> 
    <li>
      <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl(); ?>">
        <?php echo $category->getName(); ?>
      </a>
    </li>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Request the category model with `Mage::getModel()` then load instance with ID 99 and retrieve its URL and its name. Then get its children in an array and go into a `foreach` loop (with the PHP alternate control structure with the colon and `endforeach`).

Comment: I thought I had this solved but <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl(); ?>"> isn't finding the correct url of the child category. It's showing the current category url. How can I get the correct child category url to show.

Comment: I am not an expert in Magento. I just helped splitting the answer and the question.